# Custom ormlite query implementation based on class interface

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I'd like to extend certain ORMLite methods based on the object's implementation. E.g.,

I have an interface:

```
public interface IHaveTimestamps 
{
    DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    DateTime UpdatedOn { get; set; }
}
```

Now I'd like to override the `Db.Insert<T>()` method only if `T` implements `IHaveTimestamps` and for other instances of T, it should perform the `Insert` based on the default behaviour.

This is so that I can centralise setting the CreatedOn and UpdatedOn values, rather than doing that manually everywhere.

Can I do this by overloading the Insert/Update method so that all I would need to do is update the models to inherit from the interface and all the DB operations will take care of itself, or would I need to do something like this:

```
public static class DbExtensions
{
    public static long MyInsert<T> (this IDbConnection dbConn, T obj, bool selectIdentity = false) where T : IHaveTimestamps {
        obj.CreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
        obj.UpdatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
        return dbConn.Insert<T>(obj);
    }

    public static long MyUpdate<T> (this IDbConnection dbConn, T obj) where T : IHaveTimestamps {
        obj.UpdatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
        return dbConn.Update<T>(obj);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [OrmLite Global Insert/Update Filters](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#global-insert--update-filters) which already allows you to do something like this, e.g:

```
public interface IAudit 
{
    DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
}

OrmLiteConfig.InsertFilter = (dbCmd, row) => {
    var auditRow = row as IAudit;
    if (auditRow != null)
        auditRow.CreatedDate = auditRow.ModifiedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
};

OrmLiteConfig.UpdateFilter = (dbCmd, row) => {
    var auditRow = row as IAudit;
    if (auditRow != null)
        auditRow.ModifiedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
};
```

Comment: This is sooooooooooo smart!

Comment: @mythz is it possible to inject the Request object into these filters so that I can implement queries which are automatically filtered by the User/Tenant Id

Comment: @vonec No, OrmLite doesn't have any dependencies on ServiceStack.

Comment: @mythz also using UpdateOnly would mean some parts of my app that implement IAudit would still need to remember to update these fields manually?

Comment: @mythz you might want to add a note to the documentation as this won't work if you are using UpdateOnly and you don't specify the ModifiedDate in the fields to update.